# How to open a gmail/outlook compose screen on clicking a button in Desktop application?

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am trying to open up Gmail Compose screen when a button is clicked in my Desktop App. What do I need to do?

Any kind of insights is appreciated.

Comment: have a look at google api;s

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it isn't possible to specify which mail application/service to use, as it's set by the user in their browser/system settings.